# How to instaniate Model object from data in code?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

How to instaniate the model object from some data object to run validation with `isValid` method? Is there constructor method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the model itself.

```
var data = {name: 'a'};
var obj = new app.models.MyModel(data);
obj.isValid(function(valid){
  if(valid === false){
    console.log(obj.errors);
  }
});
```